# Unterminated string constant Script error

Tags: image

I am having the following close button image tag in my page.

`img src="@@@HtmlEncode(LanguagePath)@@@/img/header/HEADER_SIGN_IN_POPIN_CLOSE.gif" id="quit_sign_in"  alt="@@HTMLEncodeText(LOC_SW_LOGIN_CLOSE)@@" title="@@HTMLEncodeText(LOC_SW_LOGIN_CLOSE)@@"` 

Whenever the page loads , i am getting "Unterminated string constant" error. If hover over the error message it is pointing to HEADER_SIGN_IN_POPIN_CLOSE.gif.

Can somebody tell me what could be the reason? How to solve this issue? It is pestering me for more than 5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the problem is somewhere else(In your html code). When a browser gives an unterminated string error, it means that you have opened a double/single quote somewhere and have not terminated it.
My suggestion is to use Firebug of firefox to debug the issue.